# How can one create and manage a phoneto: tag similar to the mailto: tag in emacs with skype?

Tags: emacs, skype, phone-number, emacs23, skype4com

Under Emacs 23, mailto:foo@foobar.foo is nicely underlined and launches the writing of an email when pressing enter on it.

Given a system with Emacs and Skype installed, is it possible to configure tag such as phoneto:+5623689753 which is automatically hilighted and launches skype on this number when pressing enter on it?

Comment: By default, Emacs does not hyperlink mailto-expressions. What type of file are we talking about here?

Comment: mailto:foo@foobar.foo works in org-mode and serveral other modes?

Answer (score 2):

For org-mode, see here: http://orgmode.org/manual/Adding-hyperlink-types.html#Adding-hyperlink-types